# asp.net (web spider)

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler

i wan to create a web spider that able to get some useful information from the other web site.
how can i get the file from the website and store into my server??
eg : 
the url of the file is http://www.abc.com/attachment.php?aid=abc
how can i let the users of my website download the file without display the page http://www.abc.com/attachment.php?aid=abc ??

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about it.

The [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class can be used to fetch web resources, such as web pages.

If you want to crawl a site you will also need to parse the content in order to follow links and download the images and other resources (CSS, Javascript etc...) - I suggest using a parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML so you can query it for these resources (that you may also want to download with `WebClient`).